# Renumber endnotes in HTML

Tags: html, regex

I've been looking at many of the proposed results on SO, after doing a thorough Google search.

Context: I'm creating an epub consisting of XHTML files. The author now wants an endnote inserted at the very beginning of the book, causing the existing endnotes to have to be renumbered. There are 222 of them, so I'd rather not do it by hand (twice!).

For our purposes the book consists of six files: `d1.xhtml` through to `d5.xhtml` and `notes.xhtml`, which holds the endnote texts.

The note numbers are identified easily enough using regex: `(>)([0-9]+)(<)`

Now, I'm just at a loss as to how to increment them. The replace function apparently cannot hold a mathematical operation, so I guess I would need a programming language to do the "+1" part. As I'm not a programmer, I thought I might ask you guys how you would go about it.

Comment: I think this is a question that is kind of hard to answer here. Different people will have different ways to do it and all would be as valid as other methods.

Comment: This is one solution with vim: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951533/search-and-replace-with-incremented-values-in-vim

Comment: Thanks, Jerry, I'm just looking for a way to get this done without getting my hands dirty (and carpal tunnel). A way in, such as, use this or that language, start with this webpage; something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have Python on your computer? If not, get it immediately (Python 3 is preferred, but this will also work with Python 2):

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r">(\d+)<")

def replace(match):
   number = int(match.group(1)) + 1
   return ">{}<".format(number)

files = ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "notes"]
for file in files:
    with open(file+".xhtml") as infile, open(file+"_new.xhtml", "w") as outfile:
        text = infile.read()
        outfile.write(regex.sub(replace, text))
```

I haven't tested it yet, but I'm pretty sure it should work.

Comment: Just installed python 3.3, opened notepad and copied your code, saved as renumber.py in the same directory as the html files and executed. It threw a syntax error on this line:     with open(file+".html") as infile, open(file+"_new.html", "w" as outfile): any idea?

Comment: @ Tim Pietzcker: Tnx, for some reason I'm getting a decoding error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 36812: character maps to <undefined>. How can I tell the script to use UTF8?

Comment: I got it to work, after some browsing on SO! Thanks a million!